# Entity framework core throwing error while inserting rows in partitioned table

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, partitioning

I have tried using entity framework core for my project.

I'm using latest PostgreSQL. And my requirement is to insert bulk data in database, which has a main table and its partitioned tables (horizontal partition).

Partitioned table are inherited from the main table and gets created in advance automatically using database triggers.

PostgreSQL has one more trigger like when the data for insertion arrives it decides in which partition table it has to insert using pre-decided column value.

(lets say there is column of timestamp and it decides according to date).

[image: Architecture like this]

The issue is when I try to insert data using EF Core methods

> (like adding model and then context.SaveChanges())

PostgreSQL throws an error of unknown exception from PgSql.

```
    {"The database operation was expected to affect 1 row(s), but actually affected 0 row(s); data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=527962 for information on understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions."}
    Data: {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
    Entries: Count = 1
    HResult: -2146233088
    HelpLink: null
    InnerException: null
    Message: "The database operation was expected to affect 1 row(s), but actually affected 0 row(s); data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=527962 for information on understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions."
    Source: "Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL"
    StackTrace: "   at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Update.Internal.NpgsqlModificationCommandBatch.Consume(RelationalDataReader reader)\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.Execute(IRelationalConnection connection)\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.Execute(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection)\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalDatabase.SaveChanges(IList`1 entries)\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(IList`1 entriesToSave)\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(StateManager stateManager, Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.<>c.<SaveChanges>b__104_0(DbContext _, ValueTuple`2 t)\r\n   at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Storage.Internal.NpgsqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 
operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChanges(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChanges()\r\n   at Efcore_testapp.Controllers.HomeController.Index() in C:\\Users\\parthraj.panchal\\source\\repos\\Efcore testapp\\Efcore testapp\\Controllers\\HomeController.cs:line 52"
    TargetSite: {Void Consume(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalDataReader)}
```

> My observation is that :-

> EF core has sent data to pgsql to insert in table T and is expecting confirmation from table T but as pgsql has inserted the data in partitioned table T2 it it sending confirmation from that T2 table .
> And thats where the conflict happens between pgsql and EF core.

> My test :

> As I once tested a scenario where I just disabled the triggers that were deciding where to insert data and all the flow working fine.

Anyone has any idea about this ?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the `create table` statement for `Table T` including the partitioning definition and the **exact** and complete error message you get.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name i have added the full error message.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name this sme operation works fine if i turn off my database triggers